Android movement detection using sensor problem
I'm using sensor movement on android (not GPS) to try detecting the movement or speed of an android phone while moving or simply being idle, I have a code here used in Android Studio but I have a problem when starting the app on the phone the speed immediately starts at 9.5m/s and it keeps fluctuating very fastly (every 100 milliseconds) all while being completely idle and not moving, and after any type of movement the speed increases a lot and also keeps fluctuating, this is my MainActivity.kt file code :
package com.example.speeddetector

import android.hardware.Sensor
import android.hardware.SensorEvent
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener
import android.hardware.SensorManager
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import kotlin.math.abs
import kotlin.math.sqrt

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), SensorEventListener {
    private var sensorManager: SensorManager? = null
    private var accelerometer: Sensor? = null
    private var speedTextView: TextView? = null
    private var i=0
    private var currentSpeed = 0f
    private var lastUpdate: Long = 0
    private var lastX = 0f
    private var lastY = 0f
    private var lastZ = 0f
    private var last_shake_time: Long = 0
    private var SHAKE_HOLDOFF_MS: Long = 5000
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        speedTextView = findViewById(R.id.speedTextView)

        sensorManager = getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE) as SensorManager
        if (sensorManager == null) {
            Log.e("MainActivity", "SensorManager is null")
            return
        }

        accelerometer = sensorManager!!.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER)
        if (accelerometer == null) {
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Accelerometer sensor not available")
            return
        }
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        if (accelerometer != null) {
            sensorManager!!.registerListener(this, accelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL)
        }
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        if (accelerometer != null) {
            sensorManager!!.unregisterListener(this)
        }
    }

    override fun onSensorChanged(event: SensorEvent) {
        if (event.sensor.type == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
            val currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
            val timeDifference = currentTime - lastUpdate

            if (timeDifference > 100) {
                lastUpdate = currentTime

                val x = event.values[0]
                val y = event.values[1]
                val z = event.values[2]

                val acceleration =
                    (abs((x + y + z - lastX - lastY - lastZ).toDouble()) / timeDifference * 10000).toFloat()

                if (acceleration > SHAKE_THRESHOLD) {
                    val shakeTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
                    Log.d(
                        "MainActivity",
                        "Shake detected, acceleration: $acceleration"
                    )
                    if (shakeTime - last_shake_time >= SHAKE_HOLDOFF_MS) {
                        i++
                        last_shake_time = shakeTime
                    }
                }

                lastX = x
                lastY = y
                lastZ = z

                currentSpeed = calculateSpeed(x, y, z)
                updateSpeed(currentSpeed)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onAccuracyChanged(sensor: Sensor, accuracy: Int) {
        // Not needed for accelerometer
    }

    private fun calculateSpeed(x: Float, y: Float, z: Float): Float {
        // Use basic physics formula to estimate speed based on acceleration
        // This is a simplified example, actual implementation may require calibration
        val acceleration =
            sqrt((x * x + y * y + z * z).toDouble()).toFloat()
        return acceleration
    }

    private fun updateSpeed(speed: Float) {
        runOnUiThread { speedTextView!!.text = "Speed: $speed m/s" }
    }

    companion object {
        private const val SHAKE_THRESHOLD = 800
    }
}

I have tried changed a lot of the values of the variables but without getting to a good result so far , what is the problem here ? what I want is simply the same thing that other speed detection apps do

You can't calculate speed from acceleration alone and the accelerometer experiences the Earth's gravity as acceleration of ~9.8m/s^2 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acceleration_due_to_gravity). So, it's a physics problem. Earth's gravity needs to deducted first and after that acceleration over time would (in theory) give a speed assuming staying still in the beginning. But it's likely to be pretty inaccurate.
